The public folder is copied twice in asar file using electron forge package
I have 200Mb of media (mostly png) in my public folder for my electron-forge app (using vite and typescript).
When I package the application with npm run package I got a big app.asar file that is something like 400Mb.
I tried to not use the asar: true option to check what is inside the folder and I noticed that it contains my .vite folder that itself contains two folders:

.vite/build that contains the content of my public folder + main.js and preload.js
.vite/renderer/main_window that contains the content of my public folder + asset folder with index file and index.html file.

I don't understand what I made wrong and how to fix this. I can edit my question to add more details and file contents if needed.

try to send this media data to some source like AWS S3 and just read the URL, every system almost uses this way, it's a more professional way and you can save how much you want without limit
